# How to create a .bat file to install docker-desktop on windows 10 pro

Tags: docker, batch-file, docker-compose, windows-10, docker-desktop

I'm creating a project that runs inside a **docker** container, my project used to run on **Linux** but now I need to add support to **Windows 10**, but the user needs to install docker I used to have a shell script **.sh** file that installs **Docker** and **docker-compose** on ubuntu.

But  I wonder if there is a easy way for the user to install docker-desktop on windows without going to the docker website and downloading the installer and installing it.

can I use a **.bat** file to automate that process and maybe use **choco** windows package manager or another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can install *Docker For Windows* using *Chocolatey*:

```
choco install docker-desktop
```

Here's the package's [page](https://chocolatey.org/packages/docker-desktop/2.3.0.4).